# Raspberry Pi 2 Internet Connection by micro-USB

Tags: connection, raspberry-pi2, beagleboneblack

I'm using a RPi 2 and I supply it by the USB port of my PC, I already have made the PC share internet by the ethernet cable. I was wondering if it's possible to establish an internet connection by the same cable that does the voltage supply for RPi?

I have this doubt because I work sometimes with a BeagleBone Black and I can make a internet sharing by the same USB cable that does the voltage supply. Which is a very pratical resource from this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RPI: The micro USB is only for power supply. You cannot use it share connection or login to RPI. RPIs can be shared internet only by using Ethernet crossover cable. AFAIK there is no particular reason why RPI like that.Most users share internet to RPI by connecting it to router or PC via Ethernet cable.

But for BBB: Yes, you can use the Powersupply cable to share the internet connection and even login in to BBB.